# Removing characters from 1st textbox that are contained in 2nd textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I am not talking about :

```
if textbox1.text.contains(textbox2.text) then
textbox1.text = ""
end if
```

But this:

If textbox1 contains any char that exists in textbox2 also,is automatically removed at button click.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like

```
textbox1.Text = new String(textbox1.Text.Except(textbox2.Text).ToArray())
```

or a simple `For Each` loop.

Comment: Will try both replies.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
  ' btn click event
  Dim unique As List(of String)
  For i As Integer = 0 to textbox2.text.length - 1
    Dim c As String = textbox2.text.substring(i,1)
    If not unique.contains(c)
      textbox1.text = textbox1.text.replace(c, "")
      unique.add(c)
    End If
  Next For
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `Regex`:

```
textbox1.Text = Regex.Replace(textbox1.Text, _
    "[" & Regex.Escape(textbox2.Text).Replace("-", "\-")  & "]", "")
```